# Analogue of eigenvalues for matrix of polynomials?

Tags: matrices, eigenfunctions, generalized-eigenvector

Let $A(x)$ be a matrix with entries that are polynomials in say $\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose furthermore that $A$ is invertible. For any fixed $x$ we can find an eigenvalue of $A$ (in $\mathbb{C}$) and this eigenvalue varies smoothly with $x$.

Is there a rational function $R(x)$ that acts as an eigenvalue for $A(x)$ for any $x$? What about a Laurent series? I suspect the answer for the first question is false in general but the second question is true. I can't find a proof though.

Comment: Just take the determinant of $A(x)$ with $x$ an unknown real number. This gives a polynomial in $t$, for example, with coefficients in $\Bbb Z[x]$.

Comment: Can solutions be written as a Laurent series in general?

Comment: @mtheorylord: What do you mean by "A is invertible"? BTW, in general, there is no reason any eigenvalue of $A$ will depend smoothly on $x$.

Answer (score 0):

With $A$ having entries in $\mathbb Z[x]$, we can find its eigenvalues in the usual way by solving the characteristic equation $\det(A- tI)=0$ for $t$, where we treat $x$ as an unknown (real number, let's say). In general then, this means solving a polynomial equation $p(t)=0$ where $p$ has coefficients in $\mathbb Z[x]$. In general you of course can't solve this for $t$ as a rational function of $x$, or even get any closed form expression.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: I'm aware, but that doesn't answer my question. Are solutions in $t$ going to be rational or Laurent series.

Comment: @mtheorylord you asked "[i]s there a rational function $R(x)$ that acts as an eigenvalue for $A(x)$ for any $x$". I answered that question, the answer is no.

Comment: Thats not obvious from what you posted, and it doesn't answer the laurent series case.

Comment: @mytheorylord sure I didn't answer the second question, but my answer should give you enough to figure it out on your own. The question is reduced to a much more elementary one with an answer you can easily search. Did you even read my answer? I said "in general you of course can't solve this for $t$ as a rational function of $x$", how is this not obviously answering your first question?

Comment: If you want to find the roots of the characteristic polynomial as a function of $x$, then you can't because you can't even do so for real coefficients.

Comment: Choose a fixed $x$. We can find a $t$ that satisfies. Now perturb $x$ by a little, since the coefficients move smoothly we the solutions must differ smoothly. Choose a function $t = F(x)$ that parameterizes these solutions. Since $F$ is smooth  it must have a Laurent series. Doesn't this work? It's sketchy so I'm not sure.